# Modeling egg shaped stars

Tags: star, mathematics, modeling

I am well aware of [one-dimensional stellar models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_structure#Equations_of_stellar_structure):

> The simplest commonly used model of stellar structure is the spherically symmetric quasi-static model, which assumes that a star is in a steady state and that it is spherically symmetric.  It contains four basic first-order differential equations: two represent how matter and pressure vary with radius; two represent how temperature and luminosity vary with radius.

But what if we moved from spherical symmetry to cylindrical symmetry? **Did somebody already set up all equations and solve them for general rotational symmetric ellipsoid?**

What changes, if we would assume a [lemon-shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_(geometry)) or (most interestingly) an [egg-shaped](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm) star?

What would be the (intutive) results of such a stellar model? I am sure, somebody solved the equations already and I am just missing the appropriate search terms.

#### References

- [The mathematics of egg shape](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259604597_The_mathematics_of_egg_shape) gives a brief mathematical background about one of my favorite mathematical objects

Cylindrical symmetry is not as hypothetical as it might sound:

- Ashley Strickland wrote for CNN about "[Unusual tear-drop shaped, half-pulsating star discovered by amateur astronomers](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/03/09/world/pulsating-star-discovery-scn/index.html)"
- [WASP-12b](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WASP-12b) is is reviewed by NASA as [An egg-shaped planet](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/news/1375/wasp-12b-an-egg-shaped-planet/).

The pre-print by E.C. & L.V. Nolan [On isotropic cylindrically symmetric stellar models](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0407041) seems to cover the topic, but is not too intuitive.

#### Related

- [Can a donut-shape planet or star be formed?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27615/can-a-donut-shape-planet-or-star-be-formed)

Comment: This is fascinating! If you allow for significant rotation there are some things to explore: [What exactly was Lagrange's “grave mistake” with respect to rotating bodies under hydrostatic equilibrium?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11351/3869) and [How does a Maclaurin spheroid become a Jacobi ellipsoid? What happens?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3514142) Both are currently unanswered.

Comment: Maybe helpful, if you want to do it from scratch: Some [mathematical fun with boiling eggs](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/CDHW/egg/CW061201-1.pdf) which is mainly solving the heat conduction equation.

Comment: In principle a cylindrical symmetry might well be that of a the collapsing nebula, at start

Comment: Models of stars filling their Roche lobe would also naturally be egg-shaped. Sounds like something there should be simulations of.

Comment: As I mentioned [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20823/shape-of-neutron-stars#comment35129_20823) it's possible that the intense magnetic field of a young magnetar can distort it into a prolate (egg / football shaped) spheroid. Also see https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2162

Answer (score 1):

**Diclaimer:** *This is not (yet) an answer! To attract answers, I decided to start an answer draft which can be expanded by others.*

#### Cylindrical coordinates

Every point in our [cylindrical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) is defined by a tuple $(r,\varphi,z)$ where $r$ is the distance from the rotational axis. We also define $Z$ as the height of our [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution), i.e. $0 \leq z \leq Z$. The shape of the body is defined by shape function $s(z)$.

The volume $V$ of the object is then given by $$V= \pi \int_0^Z \left( s(z) \right)^2 {\rm d}z$$

#### Mass conservation

The mass density $\rho(r,z)$ does not depend on $\varphi$.

*to be continued*

## Specific shape curves

Up to now, all maths has been performed for a general shape function $s(z)$, so let us now look at some specific ones

### Egg as rotational body

For an egg with $z$ being the distance from the symmetry axis, we could for instance a formula by [Narushin](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248562638_The_Avian_Egg_Geometrical_Description_and_Calculation_of_Parameters):

$$s(z) = 1.5396 \cdot \frac{B}{Z} \cdot\sqrt{ \sqrt{Z}\cdot z^{\frac{3}{2}}-z^2}$$

In this formula, $B$ is the maximum breadth and $Z$ is the height of the egg.

Comment: I thought so. Graphed it on desmos, with B and Z being variables, z being the x. Use +- for the egg.